# Loop lm by year

Tags: r, group-by, lm

I have a data frame in R that looks like above

```
Id  ln_W  Year  Exp 
1   2.5   2010   15
1   2.3   2011   16
2   2.1   2010   20
3   2.5   2012   17
3   2.5   2013   18
```

I want to regress ln_W~Exp by each year in my dataset and save the summary of the results in a list format.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by `Year` and then save `lm` summary as a list-column:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(fit = list(lm(ln_W ~ Exp, data = cur_data()) %>% summary))
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 2
   Year fit       
  <int> <list>    
1  2010 <smmry.lm>
2  2011 <smmry.lm>
3  2012 <smmry.lm>
4  2013 <smmry.lm>
```

Get just the list of summaries by adding `%>% pull(fit)` to the chain.
(Note that, for the data provided, these summaries won't show much, just the intercept, as there are insufficient observations to fit.)

Answer (score 3):

In `base R`, we `split` by the `Year`, loop over the `list` with `lapply`, create the model with `lm` and store the output as a `list`

```
out <- lapply(split(df1, df1$Year), function(x)
                   lm(ln_W ~ Exp, data = x))
```

NOTE: This doesn't require any packages

---

Or another option is `lmList` from `lme4`

```
library(lme4)
lmList(ln_W  ~Exp | Year, data = df1)
#Call: lmList(formula = ln_W ~ Exp | Year, data = df1) 
#Coefficients:
#     (Intercept)   Exp
#2010         3.7 -0.08
#2011         2.3    NA
#2012         2.5    NA
#2013         2.5    NA

#Degrees of freedom: 5 total; -3 residual
#Residual standard error: 0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), ln_W = c(2.5, 2.3, 
2.1, 2.5, 2.5), Year = c(2010L, 2011L, 2010L, 2012L, 2013L), 
    Exp = c(15L, 16L, 20L, 17L, 18L)), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `by`.

```
res <- lapply(by(d, d$Year, lm, formula=ln_W ~ Exp), summary)
res
# $`2010`
# 
# Call:
# FUN(formula = ..1, data = data[x, , drop = FALSE])
# 
# Residuals:
#   ALL 2 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!
#   
#   Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)     3.70         NA      NA       NA
# Exp            -0.08         NA      NA       NA
# 
# Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:      1,   Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
# F-statistic:   NaN on 1 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
# 
# 
# $`2011`
# 
# Call:
# FUN(formula = ..1, data = data[x, , drop = FALSE])
# 
# Residuals:
#   ALL 1 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!
#   
#   Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
# Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)      2.3         NA      NA       NA
# Exp               NA         NA      NA       NA
# 
# Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
# [...]
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(Id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), ln_W = c(2.5, 2.3, 
2.1, 2.5, 2.5), Year = c(2010L, 2011L, 2010L, 2012L, 2013L), 
    Exp = c(15L, 16L, 20L, 17L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```